# Is Javascript website always send request with client's IP?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I don't know how to say this correctly since I just begin to learn JS.
But here's the scheme.

- I am trying to make a very simple Facebook tool to update status and upload it to online hosting.
- If i use PHP, Facebook will read the request comes from my hosting's IP. If there're 10 people use my tool, Facebook read those 10 requests come from the same place (hosting's IP). Which is *not* good, because Facebook will ban it.
- If i use Javascript, will the IP become different according to user's IP? So Facebook will read the requests come from 10 different places. If it's not, how to configure to make the website run with client's IP? Because it's safer.

I am using native JS and jQuery. Not framework.

Comment: No, Facebook will not ban your app just because 10 users are using it, and the API requests are send from the same server IP. If you got blocked, then likely you did something else wrong. (Post spam, post the exact same content multiple times, ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if your tool runs on the user's computer (for example in their web browser), it will access Facebook directly from their system, so Facebook will get to see the individual's IP (each one different).

Comment: What if there are several client devices on a home network connecting through the same router? To the outside world they may all present as having the same IP, no?

Comment: Yes. Also in office situations.

Comment: Thank you so much :) your answer is really helpful :D